# Rolling dice project: code gives out of bounds exception below 7 and fails to save the first "Die Number"

Tags: java, arrays, random

I understand what out of bounds exception means, and how it happens, but I can't find out why it's happening in my code. Also, the output "Count for side 1" always states 0. This is my first post, but I think I am posting this right.

This is where I think the problem is.

```
System.out.println("Now rolling " + chosenRollNumber + " times. ");
            int[] count = new int[chosenRollNumber];
            for (x = 0; x < chosenRollNumber; x++) {
                dieNumber = RNG(randomNum, min, max);
                System.out.println("dieNumber " + dieNumber);
                count[dieNumber]++;

            }
            System.out.println("Done rolling all dice");    
            for(x = 0; x < numberOfSides; x++) {
                System.out.println("Count for side " + (x + 1) + " is " + count[x]);            }

            while(true) {
```

Comment: Hint: `chosenRollNumber` has nothing to do with `numberOfSides`.

Comment: You might want to take a step back, flesh out what you are trying to achieve on a piece of paper, and *then* dive back into coding.

Comment: Check if dieNumber greater than size of count array. a.i. dieNumber <= chosenRollNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `RNG(randomNum, min, max)` is expected to return values in the range `[min...max]` (inclusive), while `dieNumber` as the index in `count` array needs to be in the range `[0; numberOfSides)`, and the following relation exists  `numberOfSides == max - min + 1`.

So, a correction is needed to transform `dieNumber` into a valid index:

```java
System.out.println("Now rolling " + chosenRollNumber + " times. ");
int[] count = new int[numberOfSides];
for (x = 0; x < chosenRollNumber; x++) {
    dieNumber = RNG(randomNum, min, max);
    System.out.println("dieNumber " + dieNumber);
    int dieIndex = (dieNumber - min) % numberOfSides;
    count[dieIndex]++;
}
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something, but it never occurred to me that I should use modulo. I have been googling off and on for most of today. Huge thank you. I marked this answer as useful, but it didn't seem to count. +1

Comment: @arcticsnowpup, you could also try accepting the answer if it was helpful as explained here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?